# Clear form with jQuery breaks success message

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a simple form where you input an email then submit. The form is sent via jquery to a php script which sends the email (if email is valid) returns a JSON response and then the jquery shows a success or failure message in a div based on the response. Got all that working.

What I want to do is clear the form if it is validated as a successful send. I can clear the form field and show the success/failure message with no problem, but found one bug. If someone inputs another email into the form, then the success (or fail) message doesn't appear. However, the php is still executing the data (sending the email) correctly. Only the success/fail message is missing. The success/fail message works the first time you submit the form, but after reset it doesn't. Here is the form:

```
<form action="" id="emailsend" method="post" >
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ; />
</form>
```

Div where success/fail message appears:

```
<div id="formResponse"></div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

$("#emailsend").submit(function(){  

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "sendunit4.php",  
        data: $("#emailsend").serialize(),  
        dataType: "json",  

        success: function(msg){  
            $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');  
            $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');  
            $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.status);  
            $("#formResponse").html(msg.message);
            $('#formResponse').fadeOut(2000);
            $('#emailsend')[0].reset();



        },  
        error: function(){  
            $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');  
            $("#formResponse").addClass('error');  
            $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");  
        }  
    });  

    return false;  

});  

});
```

Relavent part of PHP script (sendunit4.php):

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
$response_array['status'] = 'success';  
$response_array['message'] = 'Email sent!';
}
else{
$response_array['status'] = 'error';  
$response_array['message'] = 'There was a problem sending';  
}
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you opened up the network tab in your favorite inspector and checked to see what the request/response looks like?

Comment: Yes...response is the same the first and second time it is submitted. '{"status":"success","message":"Email sent!"}'

Comment: You should redirect the user to another page when he/she submit form. It will prevent user to send duplicate form

Comment: But I need people to be able to submit another email address (it's not a signup form, but an internal comms tool). Don't want duplicates sent, but was hoping clearing the form would take care of that and I know the way it is now the form doesn't resubmit automatically if you reload or use the back button. Not sure redirect is necessary.